# is there a tree list component in objective C

Tags: iphone

i have to developp a planning app on the iPhone,
a tree list view will help me a lot to structure 
the tasks like in a gantt diagramm

is there tree list component that i can use in interface builder or objective C?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple doesn't provide a tree-type UI component on iOS.  Sorry.  You'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get structure wise is using multiple UITableViewController instances in a UINavigationController (acts like a tree). However, if you are looking to generate a graphical representation, it might be worth taking a look at [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). I can't recall if they had a Gantt but it would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a Class subclass of UIView.